# Why are fonts in UI segment control reverting to system fonts automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have several UI Segment Controls across an iOS app written in swift.

Whilst simulating on an iOS device, on the initial load they use the correct custom font set in the code but certain instances where I go to other views and come back, the fonts in the segment control tabs seem to revert to system fonts automatically.

What is causing this issue?

I am creating all of my segmented controls using this function in each view controller. This is where the custom fonts are set.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    isHirer = AppSettings.boolValue(.isHirer)
    setupUI()
    setupSegmentControl()
    downloadData()
    configureLocationManager()
    
}



    func setupSegmentControl() {
    var items = [String]()
    
    items = AppSettings.boolValue(.isHirer) ? ["Posts", "Manage"] : ["Search", "Manage"]
    
    let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1), NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.init(name: "Cabin-SemiBold", size: 16)!], for: .selected)
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 138/255, green: 145/255, blue: 172/255, alpha: 0.7), NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.init(name: "Cabin-SemiBold", size: 16)!], for: .normal)
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 42, width: tableView.frame.width/2-20, height: 48)
    
    
    if AppSettings.boolValue(.isHirer) {
        segmentedControl.setContentOffset(CGSize(width: 0, height: -5), forSegmentAt: 0)
        segmentedControl.setContentOffset(CGSize(width: 0, height: -5), forSegmentAt: 1)
    } else {
        segmentedControl.setContentOffset(CGSize(width: 5, height: -5), forSegmentAt: 0)
        segmentedControl.setContentOffset(CGSize(width: 0, height: -5), forSegmentAt: 1)
    }

    
    segmentedControl.setBackgroundImage(backgroundWithColor(color: .backgroundGray, frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: segmentedControl.frame.width, height: segmentedControl.frame.height)), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    segmentedControl.setDividerImage(imageWithColor(color: UIColor.white), forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showSection), for: .valueChanged)
    seg = segmentedControl
}

@objc func showSection(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        isSegment0 = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    case 1:
        isSegment0 = false
        tableView.reloadData()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Then in ViewForHeaderInSection function of table view added seg to the header view.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    
    if section == 0 && AppSettings.boolValue(.isHirer) || section == 0 && !AppSettings.boolValue(.isHirer) {
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 90))
        headerView.backgroundColor = .backgroundGray
   

        
        let segmentControl = seg
        segmentControl.tag = section

        headerView.addSubview(segmentControl)

        return headerView
```

Comment: please enhance your question with relevant code and screenshots, you've not provided enough information for anyone to help

Comment: @CSmith added my code now too

Comment: No, you are not showing how / when that method is called. The idea of using a static method here is already quite dubious. And why a completion handler?? It’s not asynchronous. Very weird.

Comment: @matt my bad, got lost in my own code, that was just something i was initially testing to create segmented controls quicker in a repeatable way across controllers it's not being used. I've updated with the actual code in use.

Comment: still some things missing, your `setupSegmentControl()` code is creating a `UISegmentedControl`, and assigning it to what is presumably a class variable called `seg`, but we don't see how this control is added to your view hierarchy ... i.e. what are you doing with `seg`?

Comment: @CSmith i;m then adding seg in the viewForHeaderInSection function of the table view. It's a huge a function because there are many other sections so i didn't copy it in here but it's simply adding seg into a header view for that particular section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try modifying your code as follows:

**Before**:

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(...)
```

**After**:

```
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(...)
```

i.e. do not use appearance proxy on the `UISegmentedControl` class

The appearance proxy would typically be done once in an app early in its lifecycle *before* any controls of that class are instantiated.  For example, you might instead use the appearance proxy in your AppDelegates `didFinishLaunching()` API, this would replace the need to call `setTitleTextAttributes()` elsewhere in your code.

Please report back if this helps.

Comment: I've made the change, it's unclear what causes it to change. The custom fonts are applied initially when loaded but after moving around and doing other things in the app something triggers the font of these controls to revert to system but only happens sporadically therefore hard to reproduce. I will test everything i can and report if it this is the solution. thx

Comment: make sure to not call `UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes()` anywhere in your code, unless you opt to do this once as described in my edited answer.